# How do I sort 2 lists by the same criteria?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

```
public void sort() 
{
    datelist = new List<DateTime>(rdate);   //timedates
    intlist = new List <Int>(rint);         //integers

    datelist.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); //sorts the dates ascending(I think)
}
```

I have two initial arrays; these match by index number. I have converted these to lists in order to sort them. How would I sort intlist in exactly the same way as the datelist? Thanks.

Comment: arguably if the data from datelist and intlist is related it should be held in a data structure that contains the related properties

Comment: Please see my edited answer for some thoughts on why you should just use Array.Sort (assuming that you don't take @BrokenGlass's very good advice and create a class or struct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have linq at your disposal (.net 3.5 +) you can do the following.

```
// Define your collections
var dates = new[]
                {
                    new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), new DateTime(2012, 1, 2), new DateTime(2012, 1, 5),
                    new DateTime(2012, 1, 3)
                };
var ints = new[] {1,2,4,3};

var result = dates
    .Select((d, i) => new {Date = d, Int = ints[i]}) // This joins the arrays based on index
    .OrderBy(o => o.Date) // Sort by whatever field you want
    .ToArray(); // Return the results an array

// Extract just the dates
dates = result.Select(o => o.Date).ToArray();
// Extract just the ints
ints = result.Select(o => o.Int).ToArray();
```

Comment: The first ToArray call isn't necessary; did you include it for performance reasons?  I believe the ordered enumerable created by OrderBy will cache the anonymous objects, so they won't be allocated twice when you iterate twice to create the two output arrays.

Comment: True enough. I just wanted to show you could get both objects in an array, or you could have them seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create lists; use one of the static Array.Sort overloads that takes two array parameters.  The method sorts both arrays in the order specified by the values in the "keys" array, using either the default comparer or a comparer that you provide.

**EDIT**

In revisiting this answer because of a recent upvote (thank you, upvoter!), I would like to underscore that the Array.Sort solution uses far less code and far less memory overhead/garbage collection pressure:

```
public void sort()  
{
    Array.Sort(rint, rdate); //sorts both arrays in the order dictated by the ints
}
```

OR

```
public void sort()  
{
    Array.Sort(rdate, rint); //sorts both arrays in the order dictated by the dates
}
```

In SynXsiS's code, you're allocating a new anonymous object for each date/int pair, as well as another array to hold them(private to the OrderedEnumerable returned by the OrderBy call), plus *another* array to hold them (the ToArray call, which could probably be omitted), and then you're iterating that array twice to create two *more* arrays.

If these performance considerations aren't important (and mostly likely they aren't), I would still choose the Array.Sort solution on the grounds of shorter code.

As a final thought, SynXsiS's solution would benefit from Enumerable.Zip:

```
result = dates.Zip(ints, (d, i) => new { Date = d, Int = i }).OrderBy(o => o.Date);
dates = result.Select(o => o.Date).ToArray();
ints = result.Select(o => o.Int).ToArray();
```